# delete all associations based on userid in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to delete all associations based on user id. I have data like this

```
enter code here
Array
(
[id] => 1
[title] => Mr
[firstname] => kunal
[lastname] => mahajan
[business_email] => abc@gmail.com
[username] => kunal
[website] => 
[email] => kunal@gmail.com
[address] => 
[image] => 
[password] => $2y$10$nk1O1jD38dLN4xlBpkj1feJYIj9nH17.v3jMTO1jdTn9V7Mv0SUBW
[decrypt_password] => 123456
[phonenumber] => 01610524545
[mobile] => 7837329321
[remember_token] => 
[email_verify] => 0
[status] => 0
[activation_key] => 
[created_at] => 2016-11-12 06:25:48
[updated_at] => 2016-11-12 06:25:48
[listings] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [user_id] => 1
        [property] => 
        [type] => premimum
        [service_name] => Courses
        [business_name] => kunal
        [about] => ore ipsum is dummy text.
        [address] => 
        [instagram] => www.instagram.com
        [facebook] => www.facebook.com
        [pinterest] => www.pinterest.com
        [twitter] => www.twitter.com
        [youtube] => www.youtube.com
        [certifications] => Lorem ipsum is dummy text
        [days] => 
        [from] => 
        [to] => 
        [location] => Ludhiana, Punjab, India
        [postcode] => 
        [borough] => 
        [town] => 
        [latitude] => 30.9058885
        [longitude] => 75.8359645
        [squarefeet] => 
        [pricerange] => 
        [turnover] => 
        [netprofit] => 
        [information] => Lorem ipsum is dmmy text
        [other] => 
        [facilities] => 
        [premises] => 
        [expansion] => 
        [reason] => 
        [competition] => 
        [established] => 
        [support] => 
        [employees] => 0
        [furniture] => 
        [inventory] => 
        [created_at] => 2016-11-12 06:25:48
        [updated_at] => 2016-11-12 06:25:48
        [listingimage] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 1
                        [list_id] => 1
                        [image] => 602758083.jpg
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 2
                        [list_id] => 1
                        [image] => 631874072.jpg
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 3
                        [list_id] => 1
                        [image] => 572143726.jpg
                    )

                [3] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 4
                        [list_id] => 1
                        [image] => 845492008.jpg
                    )

                [4] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 5
                        [list_id] => 1
                        [image] => 22020276.jpeg
                    )

                [5] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 6
                        [list_id] => 1
                        [image] => 337797369.jpg
                    )

            )

        [courses] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 1
                        [list_id] => 1
                        [user_id] => 1
                        [course] => Nails Course
                        [fees] => 150
                        [weblink] => www.nails.com
                        [details] => Lorem ipsum is dummy text
                        [coursetype] => Part Time
                        [duration] => 6months
                        [requirement] => 15 Students
                        [certificate] => Lorem ipsum is dummy text.Lorem ipsum is dummy text.Lorem ipsum is dummy text.
                        [created_at] => 2016-11-12 06:25:48
                        [updated_at] => 2016-11-12 06:25:48
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 2
                        [list_id] => 1
                        [user_id] => 1
                        [course] => Skin Course
                        [fees] => 1500
                        [weblink] => www.skin.com
                        [details] => Lorem ipsum is dummy text
                        [coursetype] => Full Time
                        [duration] => 2 months
                        [requirement] => 10 students
                        [certificate] => Lorem ip[sum is dummy text
                        [created_at] => 2016-11-12 06:25:48
                        [updated_at] => 2016-11-12 06:25:48
                    )

            )

        [fitness_services] => Array
            (
            )

    )
)
```

I run this query but i gives me error message call to member function listings()
i have code :-

```
enter code here
$alldata = SessionUser::with('listings')->findOrFail($userid);
$alldata = json_decode(json_encode($alldata),true);
echo "<pre>"; print_r($alldata); die; // This query fetch all data
$deletedata = SessionUser::find($userid);
$deletedata =json_decode(json_encode($deleteSessiondata),true); 
$deletedata->listings()->delete();// This query doesn't work
```

Can anyone help me out for this. Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 0):

You can take the use of [Laravel's event handlers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#events) - `deleting` event to solve your problem:

```
class User extends Eloquent
{
    public function listings()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Listing');
    }

    // this is a recommended way to declare event handlers
    protected static function boot() {
        parent::boot();

        static::deleting(function($user) { // before delete() method call this
             $user->listings()->delete();
             // do the rest of the cleanup...
        });
    }
}

class Listing extends Eloquent
{
    public function photo()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Photo');
    }

    // this is a recommended way to declare event handlers
    protected static function boot() {
        parent::boot();

        static::deleting(function($listing) { // before delete() method call this
             $listing->photo()->delete();
             // do the rest of the cleanup...
        });
    }
}
```

> Eloquent models fire several events, allowing you to hook into various
>   points in the model's lifecycle using the following methods: `creating`,
>   `created`, `updating`, `updated`, `saving`, `saved`, `deleting`,  `deleted`,
>   `restoring`, `restored`. Events allow you to easily execute code each time
>   a specific model class is saved or updated in the database.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for reply i want to delete this data at a particular function i have SessionUserModel. This all data are stored in temporary tables when user completes the registration all data deleted from the session tables and transferred to the real tables. Hope you understand my concept